# VS Server Explorer - Azure Web Apps / Unable to Access App Service node

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, .net-core, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm getting the following error when I try to access the **App Service node** in the **Server Explorer** after connecting to my **Azure Subscription**.

[image]

Here's the complete **Error Message**.

```
---------------------------
Server Explorer
---------------------------
Unable to retrieve Web Apps from some subscriptions:



Subscription Visual Studio Premium with MSDN: The resource type 'apiapps' 
could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.AppService' for api version 
'2015-03-01-preview'. The supported api-versions are '2015-03-01-alpha'.

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I am able to access other nodes, just not the App Service node wherein I have 2 Apps installed and running. 1 is a Web App, the other is an Api App that I originally published as a **ASP.Net Core API App**.

Due to this, I'm having to FTP into the Site and browse through log files and download them to view them. Very time consuming and distressing.

Even after I deleted the **ASP.Net Core API app** I am still not able to access this node from within **Visual Studio 2015**.